# how to check if command line argument is given or not?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I need to code a program which set a size of integer from the command line argument.if any command line argument exist,it will set the size according that input.otherwise a default value will be set. Suppose I don't push any command line args. how can my program detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

The array `args` will have length == 0